# How to assign Html Code or RTF CODE to Excel Cell for Formatted Text

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign the RTF or HTML Code to Excel Cell in C#, but it showing the rtf code and html code , Not the actual formatted text,

For Showing the Formatted text by using RTF Code and HTML code which properties i have to change for cell of Excel in C#,

Assign RTF / HTML Code to Excel Cell for Formatted Text.

Pleas help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not very clear. Edit your question giving an example.